# get top 3 result from foreach loop in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have an array to loop in smarty. My array look like this:
Array(
   [0]=>(
      [title] = 'some title'
      [url] = 'image url'
   )
)....

I loop it in file .tpl and I just want to get top 3 result from this array. My array has the number of item larger than 3. I'm a beginner of smarty someone help me fix this problem.
Thank you very much for reading my situation!!

Comment: you click the check mark next to the answer that helped you. Like FractalizeR's for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is the array you posted:

```
$array = array( array('title' => 'title1', 'url' => 'url 1'),
                      array('title' => 'title2', 'url' => 'url 2'),
                      array('title' => 'title3', 'url' => 'url 3'),
                      array('title' => 'title4', 'url' => 'url 4'),
                      array('title' => 'title5', 'url' => 'url 5'));
```

you can use 'section' with 'max' attribute to loop through the first 3 results:

```
{section name=id loop=$array max=3}
    Title {$smarty.section.id.iteration}: {$array[id].title} 

    URL {$smarty.section.id.iteration}: {$array[id].url} 
 
{/section}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use {section}: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.section.php

Comment: Thank you Fractalize, now I can do it!

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about Smarty, but...

...If you're interested in just the first three elements of a large array, why don't you use a for loop instead of a foreach?

Comment: uh I quite lazy to change my code Roberto, but if I have no wayout may be I will..

Answer (score 0):

I have to out put top 3 results from my array with three difference div layout. The first div is the biggest and the other two div under it in the same row. I add this item
array['stt'] = 0
array['stt'] = 1
and in tpl I check {if $array.stt == 1} or {$array.stt == 0} to write out the div with the class I want, I think its not the best way but I can work exactly what I want!!
@Kailas Badu: you write carefully and easy to know, thank you very much!